Unable to use format style 'percent-fixed' on Lightning Datatable
On Lightning Datatable I'm trying to use a column of Type percent or number with the typeAttribute formatStyle:'percent-fixed' to prevent the value from being multiplied by 100.
As per the datatable documentation I should be able to pass the attribute to the child lightning-formatted-number, but it completely ignores the style.
Sample code:
columns = [
        { label: 'sumLabel', fieldName: 'sumField__c', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true, sortable: 'true', type: 'percent',
            typeAttributes: { minimumFractionDigits: '2', formatStyle:'percent-fixed' },
            cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }
        }]

I would like to prevent manipulating the data, I just want to add a % symbol to the current values and adding an icon looks weird.
DataTable documentation
FormattedNumber documentation
Am I trying to set the format correctly?
Appreciate any help!

Does this answer your question? How to handle percentage factor of 100 problems when using lightning:input and lightning:datatable?

Check this -https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4SNRSA3

Hi, thanks for replying. One is regarding an aura component, not lwc. The other one refers to another issue. The documentation states I should be able to format the child formatted number component (by setting the formatStyle:'percent-fixed'). I wanted to know if this is not intended to work like this or it's a component issue.
This thread in the lwc repo states that this issue should be reported here:
https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2315
